# What determines the value/price of an ETF

Tags: etf, book-value

An ETF is a collection of shares packaged into a single tradeable equity.
But since the marketvalue of an ETF unit is determined by market forces, what impact does the change in value of an individual shares apart of ETF have.

e.g A Tech ETF holds shares of Apple, Google, and Amazon, if the share price of Google goes up, how is that reflected in the price of the ETF

Comment: If the market price of an ETF deviates significantly from its net asset value (NAV), high-frequency traders will arbitrage it away. See https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/032615/how-etf-arbitrage-works.asp, for example.